# умножить дату на число

Tags: php

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php"> 
<input type="date"  name="date_one" >
<input type="date"  name="date_two" >
<input type="submit" size="50" name="interval">
</form>
```

есть форма , в неё вставляются две даты, и находится разница между ними

```
$datetime1 = date_create($_POST['date_one']);
$datetime2 = date_create($_POST['date_two']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a');
```

например в первую дату взять 02.09.2000 , а в вторую дату 02.09.2016 
разница получается 5844 дня отлично теперь вот это получившиеся число мне надо умножить на 1.5 , и получившиеся число перевести в  год, месяц, день.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что дубликат самого себя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561734